# Fabric.js and <Video>

Tags: html, video, fabricjs

I want to draw shapes with by using fabric.js on a video element. I am quite new to JavaScrpit, jQuery & fabric.js.

I would be grateful if someone can give me some assistance whether this is possible. Some sample lines would be very helpful.

Drawing on an image (png) has been no issue as fabric.js offers this out of the box. However with video element I am not finding the expected result.

Comment: There's no built-in support for video elements in fabric. It sounds like a nice feature to have though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw shape on video, You must be define fabric canvas on video.
when you are define of fabric canvas, you put canvas using CSS on video.
Then you are drawing on canvas to fabric.